# How to scrape a table with a blind caption?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, caption

I'm scraping a table from a page.

But the table's caption is 'blind'.

Is there no way to extract the table from the site?

Using BeautifulSoup like:

```
from urllib.request import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Provide us link to the page and specify what exactly do you need.

Comment: I'm gonna use urlopen module for site : 'http://company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=056190'

Comment: The table I want is under ("div" , {"id"  : "cF1001"}),  embedded with ("table", {"class" : "gHead01 all-width"}). Thank you..

Comment: The site is not working

Comment: Sorry, the site was wrong...
The right one is : ("http://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=056190")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

link = 'http://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx?cn=&cmp_cd=005930&menuType=block'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(link)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id' : 'cTB24'})

for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        print(td.text)
```